# Convergence of symetric improper integrals

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

[Graph of 1 period tan(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxaAv.png)
Graphically, my intuition is that this should converge to $0$ because $f(x)=-f(-x)$
. However, WolframAlpha says the integral does not converge. I wrote this solution to show my thoughts on why my intuition is valid. How am I wrong and why is WolframAlpha right?
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}tanxdx$$
$$=\lim_{a\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-}(\int_{-a}^{a}\tan{(x)}dx)$$
$$=\lim_{a\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-}(-\ln{|\cos{(x)}|}\bigg|_{-a}^{a})$$
$$=\lim_{a\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-}(-\ln{|\cos{(a)}|+\ln{|\cos{(-a)}}|})$$
$$=\lim_{a\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-}(-\ln{|\cos{(a)}|+\ln{|\cos{(a)}}|})$$
$$=\lim_{a\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-}(0)$$
$$=0$$

Comment: Why did $\pm\infty$ vanished after the first equality?

Comment: @AnotherUser that was a mistake the bound was supposed to be $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Your first equality is invalid. All of your steps following the first equals sign are correct (except I think you wanted the limit from below) and $\lim_{a\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-}\int_{-a}^{a}\tan{(x)}\, \mathrm{d}x$ does indeed go to zero.

However, the improper integral $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan{(x)}\, \mathrm{d}x$ doesn't indicate just the symmetric limit, but rather a multivariate limit

$$\lim_{(a,b) \to (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})}\int_{a}^{b}\tan{(x)}\, \mathrm{d}x\, \text{.}$$

This limit does not converge. (In case you are unfamiliar with multivariate limits, for convergence the limit must converge along *every* path, not just some).